# This Patent has been Successfully Issued by the USPTO

Tags: procedures

In reference to the patent: [US20050165667][1]

[1]: https://www.google.com/patents/US20050165667                                Is it True that US Patent No 9,530,132 was successfully issued on December 27, 2016 ?

Comment: I've provided an answer below, since this is an answerable question. However, at first blush it seems trivial. Is there any reason you doubt the data of US 9530132 that prompted this question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

As shown in the USPTO PatFT copy of [US 9539132](http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PALL&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.htm&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=9530132.PN.&OS=PN/9530132&RS=PN/9530132), it was issued on 27 December 2016. This was initially published as US 2005/0165667 A1.